# How to get Jaccard similarity between two array columns in a table in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, statistics, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I'm basing my question is this previous one, that missed sample data and desired results:

- [How to perform Jaccard similarity between two array columns in a table in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73094537/how-to-perform-jaccard-similarity-between-two-array-columns-in-a-table-in-snowfl)

I want to write a UDF in Snowflake that can compute Jaccard similarity between two arrays:

```sql
with data as (
    select [1,2,3,4] a, [1,2,3,5] b
    union all select [20,30,90], [20,40,90]
)

select jaccard_sim(a, b)
from data
```

The desired results are 0.6 and 0.5, for the previous two examples.

Definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JS UDF to perform the desired computation:

```sql
create or replace function jaccard_sim(A array, B array)
returns string
language javascript
as $$
var union = new Set([...A, ...B]).size;

var intersection = new Set(
  Array.from(new Set(A)).filter(x => new Set(B).has(x))
).size;

return intersection/union

$$;
```

With this, `select jaccard_sim(a, b) from data` will work as expected.

I got the set operations for JS from https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sets.html#union-a-b.

---

The UDF above solves the problem. As a bonus, this is how the native Snowflake `approximate_similarity`/`approximate_jaccard_index` works:

```sql
with data as (
    select [1,2,3,4] a, [1,2,3,5] b
    union all select [20,30,90], [20,40,90]
)


select approximate_similarity(mh), seq, array_agg(arr)
from (
    select minhash(1023, value) mh, seq, any_value(a) arr
    from data, table(flatten(a))
    group by seq
    union all
    select minhash(1023, value) mh, seq, any_value(b) arr
    from data, table(flatten(b))
    group by seq
)
group by seq
```

[image]

Comment: When doing on mass, it may benefit passing through arrays_overlap() prior. This is a way more effecient function that discards arrays that cannot be similar.  This may reduce credit usage and speed things up. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/arrays_overlap.html

Comment: I'm wondering if doing the extra check adds computation time, in cases where the user expect most rows to have overlap

Comment: Absolutely there is extra computation as you know, it's detection of  overlaps vs no overlap.  I've found in most of my cases it's absolutely worth it (this is dependent on the size of each array as well - my arrays were extremely large).  The only thing I'd add is that data changes when you're not looking so some sort of regular testing maybe worthy - however your datasets size, rate of change etc etc comes into play.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa  I ended up solving the problem with using array_intersection and just calculating the union with taking the size(A) + size(B) - size(A n B). Its not a great solution for very large arrays but worked for my use case.

Comment: Oh, be careful with that solution, as you need to remove duplicates from the union